# Is codesourcery ARM Toolchain available for 64bit windows?

Tags: codesourcery

I am currently using the 32 bit codesourcery ARM toolchain for the 32 bit Windows. It's working fine, however I want to know whether a 64 bit codesourcery ARM toolchain is available?

Comment: `is available or not` - where?

Answer (score 2):

> Sourcery CodeBench is a 32-bit application, but runs on 64-bit host systems with 32-bit host libraries.

The information comes from the bottom of the web pages for specific target platforms.  Here's the page for ARM GNU/Linux targets:

http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/platforms/arm-gnulinux

Comment: What are "the" host libraries?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend against using any *Sourcery CodeBench* compilers for cross-compiling ARM code on Windows. There are way too many issues with using the windows environment and their tools. But if you do insist, much of the details can be found in the [SamyGo](http://wiki.samygo.tv/index.php5/Cross-compiling_%28ES_series%29#REQUIREMENTS.21.21) wikientry. Moreover, there is a whole range of home cooked ARM cross-compilers on the XDA forums. Like [HERE](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2098133) and [HERE](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1686310). Good Luck.