# Codesourcery toolchain under Win7/cygwin can't find some files

Tags: cygwin, codesourcery

I have searched this but the questions I found are about getting the toolchain to work, my problem is that it works on all but a few directories.  Also I am not building Linux.

I am trying to move a project from a Linux machine to Windows to make people happy.  The same project builds fine under Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) using the Linux Binary for the same toolchain (I recently reloaded both toolchains from the same directory at Mentor to be sure, see details below).

I installed Cygwin, got the packages, set up paths, etc.  In general the build works for 90% of the project BUT as make traverses the directory, it finds everything except two files (to clarify, these two are the first files in their respective directories, so I assume the problem will apply to the whole directory).  The log below shows the first fail:

- if I take lwip out of the build then it blows up on the next one
- if I take the next one out of the build then everything else (quite a bit) compiles; then the linker fails on the two missing items as expected.

More precisely, e.g.

it finds  /home/Nadi/project/version-2.9/external/freertos/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM3_MPU/port.c

but not /home/Nadi/project/version-2.9/external/lwip/src/api/api_lib.c

from the directory that I am running make, "ls" finds the file that the compiler cannot.

### log:

```
$ make
external/freertos 
external/lwip  
 [cc] Debug/api_lib.o 
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: error: /home/Nadi/project/version-2.9/external/lwip/src/api/api_lib.c: No such file or directory 
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files compilation terminated. 
Makefile:189: recipe for target `Debug/api_lib.o' failed 
make[2]: *** [Debug/api_lib.o] Error 1 
Makefile:37: recipe for target `lwip_world' failed 
make[1]: *** [lwip_world] Error 2 
Makefile:160: recipe for target `extern' failed 
make: *** [extern] Error 2
```

### Details:

- GCC Chain : arm-none-eabi-gcc ; gcc version 4.7.2 (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2012.09-63)
- Cygwin    : CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64

Comment: Do you have `cygpath` in your PATH, or do you have `$CYGPATH` set?

Comment: Don't do it. See the answer to [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358389/is-codesourcery-arm-toolchain-available-for-64bit-windows/19669965#19669965) similar question.

Answer (score 1):

Although it might not help in this particular case, I faced similar problem with CodeSourcery's gcc not recognising Cygwin's paths like `/cygdrive/d/foo.c` at all - installation of cygpath package and setting environment variable `export CYGPATH=c:/cygwin32/bin/cygpath` (or `set CYGPATH=c:/cygwin32/bin/cygpath` in windows console) solved all the issues.

Be sure to define path to cygpath executable in exactly same way as above, regardless of Cygwin or Windows console used.

Answer (score 0):

The details of my previous comment is that you're in for a lot of trouble using the windows/cygwin combo with *Sourcery* based cross-compilers. You can read more about this at [SamyGo](http://wiki.samygo.tv/index.php5/Cross-compiling_%28ES_series%29#REQUIREMENTS.21.21). Some of the issues using Windows, presented in all gory detail there, are:

> - Uses ACL to set file permissions and ownership (Not Linux compatible.)
> - Has it's own way of creating symbolic links (Not Linux compatible.)
> - Uses a non case-sensitive default for its fixed NTFS drives. 
>     (Often and silently break archives originally compressed under Linux.)
> - Uses the Win32 (non POSIX) standard for file paths (Not Linux compatible.)
> - Uses the 2 characters Carriage-Return and New-Line ("\r" & "\n") for
>     End-of-Line (EOL) representation, contrary to POSIX, which uses only NL.

So in order not to waste time doing 3rd party debugging, you'd be much better off building your own cross-compiler from scratch, as shown in the XDA links in that other post. Since the advent of Android's, this is no longer difficult.